# Mongoose schema giving the same value for the field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, uuid

```
    const nft = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        name: String,
        owner: String,
        ownerPicture: String,
        group: String,
        groupPicture: String,
        code: {
          type: String,
          default: uuidv4(),
          unique:true
        },
        producedBy: String,
        competeIn: String,
        description: String,
        nft: String,
        nftDestination: String,
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );
```

This is my mongoose Schema and it working fine. But the the default value for code is giving me the same uuid for every model. I want it to be unique every time.
When ever I make a new model of this schema. The code value always remain the same.
Please give me a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Express execute code from top to bottom. That means it will go through your code and execute `uuidv4()` that will generate unique string and Express will assume that is the default value for all documents.

In other words, `uuidv4()` will be executed only once, and not on each document generation.

I didn't test this, but you can try this:

```js
code: {
  type: String,
  default: () => uuidv4(),
  unique: true
},
```

Comment: Or just `default: uuidv4`